# Relationship between definitions of Regular Conditional Distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

There seem to be two different definitions of a regular conditional distribution, but they seem to define a slightly different kernel function. How are they connected? [Definition 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation) and [Definition 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#Formal_definition).

##### Set Up

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ a measurable space, $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ a random variable with distribution $P_X = \mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$, and $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-sigma algebra.

##### Definitions

> **Definition 1**: A kernel $k:\Omega\times \mathcal{E}\to [0, 1]$ that is a version of $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{X\in A} \mid \mathcal{G}](\omega) = k(\omega, A)$.

> **Definition 2**: A kernel $k:\mathsf{E}\times\mathcal{F}\to[0, 1]$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}(A\cap X^{-1}(B)) = \int_B k(x, A) d P_X(x)$.

It almost seems that in the second definition one uses the inverse of $X$ as the random variable of interst, but this doesn't necessarily exist.

## MAJOR EDIT

There is something really odd at play. I think there are actually many different definitions but people seem to not distinguish between them.

- Definition 1 is definitely a definition for a **regular conditional distribution of a random variable given a sub-sigma algebra**. That is $\mathbb{P}(X\in A \mid \mathcal{G})$
- Definition 2 seems to be something like a **regular conditional probability of a set given a random variable**. That is $\mathbb{P}(A \mid X = x)$.

Comment: In definition 2, tahe $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$. If you start with definition 2, then to recover definition 1, consider the random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{E})\rightarrow(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ given by $X(\omega)=\omega$. Then $\sigma(X)=\mathcal{G}$.

Answer (score 2):

In definition 1, $\kappa$ is a regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$.

In definition 2, $X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega :  X(\omega) \in B\} = \{X \in B\}$ is called the inverse image of $B$ under $X$. Definition 2 says that $P(A \mid X) = \kappa(X, A)$. So we might say that $\kappa$ is a regular conditional probability given $X$. If you define $W : \Omega \to \Omega$ by $W(\omega) = \omega$, then $\tilde{\kappa}(\omega, A) := \kappa(X(\omega), A)$ is the conditional distribution of $W$ given $\sigma(X)$. Hence definition 2 can be seen as a special case of definition 1.

Edit: I'll elaborate on definition 2. Assume definition 2 holds. Then for every $B \in \mathcal{E}$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}$,
\begin{align}
E(1_{A}1_{B}(X)) &= P(A \cap \{X \in B\}) \\
&= \int_{B}\kappa(x, A)P(X \in dx) \\
&= \int_{E}\kappa(x, A)1_{B}(x)P(X \in dx) \\
&= \int_{\Omega}\kappa(X(\omega), A)1_B(X(\omega))P(d\omega) \\
&= E(\kappa(X, A)1_{B}(X))  
\end{align}
This means that $E(1_{A} \mid X) = \kappa(X, A)$. This means that $$P(W \in A \mid X) = \kappa(X, A).$$
So $\kappa(X(\cdot), \cdot)$ is a regular conditional distribution of $W$ given $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: Mmm I am confused. A **regular conditional probability** can be found by setting $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})=(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $X$ to be the identity random variable, that is $X(\omega) = \omega$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$. The result is a kernel $k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)$. This is *similar* to definition 2, but it is not identical. Notice here we have no random variable whatsoever left (or we have the identity random variable). One can write $k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A} \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)$.

Comment: It seems that you are perhaps assuming that there exists another random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathsf{S}$ for some measurable space $(\mathsf{S}, \mathcal{S})$ and we are choosing $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$. In that case one would have $k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A} \mid \sigma(Y))(\omega) =: \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\mid Y)(\omega)$.

Comment: @Euler_Salter The thing is that $P(A \mid X) = P(A \mid \sigma(X))$ is the definition. The rhs is a conditional expectation, and the lhs is just notation we use for the rhs.

Comment: You are right $\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A} \mid Y)(\omega)$ is by definition a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}} \mid Y)(\omega)$. However I don't get the expression in Definition 2. Indeed by definition of conditional expectation one has
$$
\int_B k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) d\mathbb{P}(w) = \int_B\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\qquad \forall \, B\in\mathcal{F}
$$
But the RHS now is $\mathbb{P}(A)$ not $\mathbb{P}(A\cap Y^{-1}(B))$. And the left hand side is integrated with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ not $\mathbb{P}\circ Y^{-1}$.

Comment: Even if for some reason one would to make a typo and write the integrals above with respect to $P_Y = \mathbb{P} \circ Y^{-1}$ then the LHS would be fine but the RHS would not work out because
$$
\int_B \mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}} d P_Y = \int_{Y^{-1}(B)} \mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}}\circ Y d\mathbb{P}
$$
but what we really want on the RHS is $\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}}$ rather than $\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}} \circ Y$ so that one would get 
$$
\int_{\mathsf{A}\cap Y^{-1}(B)} d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\cap Y^{-1}(B))
$$

Comment: Actually by definition of conditional expectation one has that for $\mathsf{C}\in\sigma(Y)$
$$
\int_{\mathsf{C}} k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathsf{C}} \mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{A}}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathsf{A} \cap Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B})} d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A} \cap Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B}))
$$
since $\mathsf{C}\in\sigma(Y)$ means $\mathsf{C} = Y^{-1}(B)$ for some $\mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{S}$. This seems to solve the problem in the RHS but the LHS is still wrong

Comment: For the LHS one could write $\mathbb{P} = P_Y \circ Y$ and then use the change of variables formula I suppose
$$
\int_{\mathsf{C}} k(\omega, \mathsf{A}) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{Y(Y^{-1}(\mathsf{B}))} k(Y(\omega), \mathsf{A}) d P_Y(Y(\omega)) = \int_{\mathsf{B}} k(s, \mathsf{A}) dP_Y(s)
$$
where I have defined $s = Y(\omega)$, even though I don't know how rigorous this is.

Comment: I don't know what your question is. Definition 2 is the definition of regular conditional probability given a random variable $X$. In the discrete case, the Bayes formula is an example of a regular conditional probability given $X$.

Comment: I added a proof for my assertions about definition 2. The formula for integral wrt $P_X$ is used here.

Comment: I understand the display where you show $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_B(X)] = \mathbb{E}[k(X, A) \mathbb{1}_B(X)]$ but I don't understand how you then infer $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A\mid X] = k(X, A)$. Shouldn't it be $\mathbb{1}_A = k(X, A)$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I'm using the definition of conditional expectation and the fact that $k(X, A)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable (this is because $k$ is measurable in it's first argument by assumption). $1_A = k(X, A)$ is definitely wrong since $1_A$ takes values in $\{0, 1\}$, while $k(X, A)$ generally takes values in $[0, 1]$.